# C++ How to define array of objects (Eclipse arduino)

Tags: c++, eclipse

Going nuts trying to define an array of objects.  Thanks.

```
// Menu.h
#ifndef MENU_H_
#define MENU_H_
#include "WString.h"
class Menu {
public:
    Menu(String label);
    void addChild(String label);
    String getLabel();
private:
    Menu  childMenus[10]; ==> field 'childMenus' has incomplete type 'Menu [10]
    String label;
};
#endif /* MENU_H_ */
```

Comment: Are you sure that what you want is for each menu to create 10 more menus (which in turn create 100 more menus, etc.)? You might instead want an array of 10 pointers to menus `Menu* childMenus[10]` or a vector `std::vector<Menu> childMenus`

Comment: A `Menu` object cannot contain copies of itself. Each child menu would also contain 10 child menus, which would each contain another 10 child menus, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have the Object within the Object class. Menu should not be use in itself.

You use array of object pointers, this should work:

```
Menu* childMenus[10];
```

You would access the childMenus array like so:

```
childMenus[0]->getLabel();
```